# How to calculate Voice and Data usage in BlackBerry 10 application

Tags: blackberry-10

Hi I am developing an application in BlackBerry 10 platform which will calculate data usage and voice usage of user device for particular duration.

There are some of the feasibility check need to be done for this which are as follows

- Does BB10 API supports data usage calculation? If yes, Can I differentiate 3G/Cellular data from WiFi data?If yes, how can I achieve this?
- How can I calculate Voice usage in BB 10 application? Voice usage is nothing but duration of all calls happened within particular timespan
- Is there any API BB10 provides through which I can check if device is currently in Roaming or not?

Please let me know if this can be done in BB 10 application

Comment: It can definitely be done. There are already apps that do this. But can't help you with how. Check core documentation

Comment: I am going through documentation provided by BlackBerry and got some workaround for calculating voice usage but still struggling to get help for data usage. Also I just got API for checking if device is in roaming or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does BB10 API supports data usage calculation?**
Yes, [there are a few for API's for this](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__device__networkdatausage.html#function-networkdatausage-networkinterfacename-parent)
**Can I differentiate 3G/Cellular data from WiFi data?**
Yurp you can.

1) Add the following line to your .pro file:

```
LIBS += -lbbdevice
```

2) Make sure you include:

```
#include <bb/device/NetworkDataUsage>
```

3) Getting data useage for **cellular network only**

```
 bb::device::NetworkDataUsage *nduCell = new bb::device::NetworkDataUsage("cellular0");
 nduCell ->update();
 quint64 bytesSent      = nduCell ->bytesSent();
 quint64 bytesReceived  = nduCell ->bytesReceived();
```

4) Getting data useage for **wifi only**

```
bb::device::NetworkDataUsage *nduWifi = new bb::device::NetworkDataUsage("tiw_sta0");
nduWifi ->update();
quint64 bytesSent       = nduWifi ->bytesSent();
quint64 bytesReceived   = nduWifi ->bytesReceived();
```

That will give your the data useage since the device has started.
You will need to call ndu->update() regularly to get the most recent data usage statistics.

*Extra Info:*
Changing the parameter for the NetworkDataUsage changes the interface it minitors:
cellular0 == Cellular
tiw_sta0 == Wifi
ecm0 == USB

**To find out which interfaces are available on your device:**
1) Add the following line to your .pro file:

```
 QT += network
```

2) Make sure you include:

```
#include <QNetworkInterface>
```

3) Displaying available interfaces

```
QList<QNetworkInterface> interfaces = QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces();
for (int i = 0; i < interfaces.size(); i++) {
   qDebug() << QString::number(i) + ": " + interfaces.value(i).humanReadableName();
}
```

**How can I calculate Voice usage in BB 10 application? Voice usage is nothing but duration of all calls happened within particular timespan**

This can be done using [Phone](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__system__phone__phone.html) class.
There is signal call void callUpdated (const bb::system::phone::Call &call, ) using which we can get to know if incoming call is received or outgoing call is initiated.

With the combination of this and Timer class we can calculate Voice usage of device. (This code is not tested)

Comment: Hi iamanyone, next time i will surely ask different questions for different functionalities. For this question, your answer is covering only half part. could you please answer remaining part so that i can mark this as accepted answer.